# How to map a native query to POJO class using jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo

I am using both JPA and hibernate in my project.

I have created a query in which i made join operation on many tables. So I created a native one. The results that i get are in a list of object[] but i would like **the results to be converted automatically to a java POJO class**.
You can check both the query syntax and POJO java class below.

**JPA Query**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT obsp.Identifier, obs.phenomenontimestart, nv.value " +
        "From Series s " +
        "INNER JOIN Featureofinterest fi on s.featureofinterestid = fi.featureofinterestid " +
        "INNER JOIN ObservableProperty obsp on s.observablepropertyid = obsp.ObservablePropertyId " +
        "INNER JOIN Observation obs on s.seriesid = obs.seriesid " +
        "INNER JOIN NumericValue nv on nv.observationid = obs.observationid " +
        "where fi.identifier = ?1 and obs.phenomenontimestart >= ?2 AND obs.phenomenontimestart <= ?3 " +
        "order by obs.phenomenontimestart",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<CurrentMeasure> findCurrentMeasure(String ident, Timestamp t1, Timestamp t2);
```

**POJO class**

```
public class CurrentMeasure {

private String identifier;
private Timestamp dateTime;
private BigDecimal bigDecimal;

public CurrentMeasure() {
}

public CurrentMeasure(String identifier, Timestamp dateTime, BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
}

public String getIdentifier() {
    return identifier;
}

public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
}

public Timestamp getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(Timestamp dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public BigDecimal getBigDecimal() {
    return bigDecimal;
}

public void setBigDecimal(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
}
```

}

Comment: why use an SQL query when JPQL would do what you need? (assuming there are entities for those tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JPA you can call the constructor of your class `CurrentMeasure` directly inside your HQL query.

Example :

`SELECT NEW <package>.CurrentMeasure(obsp.Identifier, obs.phenomenontimestart, nv.value) FROM ...`

The NEW syntax is explained in [Jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html) at chapter 11.5.

Another solution would be using [HQL Transformers](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/) to achieve the same result without resorting to a constructor.