# Using Spring JPA Query to populate a pojo

Tags: spring, jpa, mapping, pojo

I am using JPA and Hibernate to carry out a simple query. It is a join pulling from two tables,  an application table, and a Transaction table. I can see data coming back but it is not able to populate this POJO I created, and it is failing to make the conversion. This is the query:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, String>{


@Query(value="SELECT "
+ " TXN.TAX_ID taxId, "
+ " APP.AP_DT  apDt, "
+ " TXN.TXN_ID txnId"
+ "      FROM "
+ " APPLICATION APP "
+ "      JOIN "
+ " TRANSACTION TXN "
+ "      ON "
+ " TXN.TXN_ID = APP.TXN_ID "
+ "     WHERE"
+ " APP.CONFIRMATION_ID = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
AnnuityNetPdfToFims getInfoForPdfToFims(String confirmationId);
```

Here is the Transaction Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"TRANSACTION\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Transaction.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Transaction t")

public class Transaction implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="TXN_ID")
private String txnId;

@Column(name="ACCT_NUM")
private String acctNum;

@Column(name="ACCT_TYPE_CODE")
private String acctTypeCode;

@Column(name="AGENT_ID")
private String agentId;

@Column(name="AUTO_SUITABILITY_IND")
private String autoSuitabilityInd;

@Column(name="CARRIER_ID")
private String carrierId;

@Column(name="CHANNEL_NAME")
private String channelName;

@Column(name="COMPANY_NAME")
private String companyName;

@Column(name="DELIVERY_STATE")
private String deliveryState;

@Column(name="FIMS_DOCUMENT_ID")
private String fimsDocumentId;

@Column(name="INTERNAL_CONVERSION_IND")
private String internalConversionInd;

@Column(name="JOINT_OWNER_STATE")
private String jointOwnerState;

@Column(name="OWNER_FIRST_NAME")
private String ownerFirstName;

@Column(name="OWNER_LAST_NAME")
private String ownerLastName;

@Column(name="OWNER_TYPE_CODE")
private String ownerTypeCode;

@Column(name="PERSON_IND")
private String personInd;

@Column(name="PRODUCT_CODE")
private String productCode;

@Column(name="PRODUCT_CUSIP")
private String productCusip;

@Column(name="RESIDENCE_STATE")
private String residenceState;

@Column(name="REVIEWER_ID")
private String reviewerId;

@Column(name="SOLICITATION_STATE")
private String solicitationState;

@Column(name="STATUS_CODE")
private String statusCode;

@Column(name="STEP_ACTION_CODE")
private String stepActionCode;

@Column(name="STEP_NAME")
private String stepName;

@Column(name="TAX_ID")
private String taxId;

@Column(name="TR_BY_ID")
private String trById;

@Column(name="TR_TS")
private Timestamp trTs;

@Column(name="TXN_QUALIFIED_IND")
private String txnQualifiedInd;

@Column(name="TXN_XML")
private String txnXml;

@Column(name="UNIT_ID")
private String unitId;

@Column(name="VENDOR_APP_ID")
private String vendorAppId;

@Column(name="G_NUM")
private String gNum;

@Column(name="XTRAC_WORKITEM_ID")
private String xtracWorkitemId;

public Transaction() {
}
//getters and setters
```

Here is the Application Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Application.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Application a")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ApplicationPK id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="AP_DT")
private Date apDt;

@Column(name="DTCC_APPSUB_XML")
private String dtccAppsubXml;

@Column(name="PROCESSING_CODE")
private String processingCode;

@Column(name="TXN_ID")
private String txnId;

public Application() {
} 
//getters and seters
```

And here is the POJO I am trying to populate with the query.

```
    public class AnnuityNetPdfToFims
{
    private String confirmationId;
    private String taxId;
    private Date   apDt;
    private long   fimsReturnNum;
    private String txnId;
    //getters and setters
```

So I can see that the data is coming back but it is coming back as an Object []. I suppose I could just use that to populate the POJO but I don't think that's very reliable. I have heard that there is a way to use the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation, but have not been able to use it successfully yet. I have also heard that i may be able to specify the actual name of the object in the query like so: [How to map a native query to POJO class using jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155529/how-to-map-a-native-query-to-pojo-class-using-jpa-and-hibernate).

However I am not able to get this to work either. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use a SQL query rather than a JPQL query? And why do you store IDs of other entities in your entities, instead of using associations. Not doing it the JPA way will always make it harder than it should be.

Comment: Yes, this is a an application we've brought over from mybatis, so I thought I could just leverage the SQL that was already written. And given that I was getting data back - I thought there wasn't anything wrong with the query and that it was just a mapping issue.